# Subject or object in the Dewey Decimal Classification

Tags: library

I'm not sure I understand how the Dewey Decimal Classification works. Do the numbers relate to the object or subject of the book?

The confusion I have comes from the fact that in my faculty library, *The Logic of Scientific Discovery* (ISBN 9780415278447) and *the Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Science* (ISBN 0190939397) have a completely different subject, the first one talks about science, the second one about philosophy, but the same number (501). And according to http://classify.oclc.org this is the choice most often made.

Comment: At the time the first book was written, the 501 classification was probably sufficiently diffuse that it fit. Also, the classifications are not made by subject matter experts, and often there are misfits. A particularly bad example that I'm aware of is [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824792300), which deals with a very specialized hard-core classical real analysis topic, but in university libraries you'll find it shelved at QA212.T49 (Library of Congress #) among books dealing with abstract algebra (specifically, symmetric functions in the theory of equations sense).